# convert fahrenheit to celsius method

Tags: java, methods

I am supposed to create a call method that will take a Fahrenheit value and return a Celsius equivalent. I know the the formula is (f-32) * 5/9 but when I enter the Fahrenheit value it is not giving me the Celsius value but it'll give me 100.0. The code is in two different files.

my code:

```
public class Temperature
{
    public static double convert(double fah) {
        double convert;
        double cel = (5/9) * fah -32;
        return fah;
    }
}

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question3
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Fahrenheit value:");
        double f = keyboard.nextDouble();
        double result = Temperature.convert(f);
        System.out.printf("Equivalent celsius value: %.1f", result);
    }
}
```

Comment: 5/9 is zero.  Make it 5.0/9.0 and you'll be fine.  Go read about integer division.

Comment: If you know the formula is `(f-32) * 5/9`, why did you write `(5/9) * f-32`? The first would have worked correctly, even with `int` literals.

Comment: You always return  `fah` from`convert`(i.e., the Fahrenheit input), not the result of your calculation.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should return celsius instead of fah
2. You should use double 5 and 9 ( so that they are considered as
   doubles instead of integers)
3. You should put fah - 32 in bracket to avoid ambiguity in arth operations (basic arth rules)

   ```
   double convert(double fah) {
       double cel = (5.0/9.0) * (fah -32);
       return cel;
   }
   ```

And as expected, it is working fine:

[image]

Comment: 100 Fahrenheit is not -32 Celcius. It is not working fine since 5/9 == 0

Comment: agreed... seems to be multiple issue with the code. Updated now.

Answer (score 1):

There is a couple problems with your code, however there is one major one and it is in your convert function

```
public static double convert(double fah) {
    double convert;
    double cel = (5/9) * fah -32;
    return fah;
}
```

Here you take a double fah, and never change it and return it. You should return the new variable cel.

```
public static double convert(double fah) {
    double cel = (5.0/9.0) * (fah -32);
    return cel;
}
```

You also had a variable that did nothing. And you should use float for division. You can also do

```
public static double convert(double fah) {
    return (5/9) * (fah -32);
}
```

This will work just fine.

Comment: thank you! i knew i was overlooking something small. I wanted to use float but we have to turn our codes into hypergrade and he gave us this demo.java file that is already pre made. This has helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Temperature
{
    public static double convert(double fah) {
        double convert;
        double cel = (5.0/9.0) * (fah -32);
        return cel;
    }
}
```